# Active Record syntax issues and looping in the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash like this:

```
POPULATION_SUMMARIES = {
    'ACO' => [   # year , member_count
        [2013, 523031],
        [2012, 492349],
        [2011, 432573]
    ]
}
```

where "ACO" is for example the name of an organization from Organization table.
And I want to insert the structure of that hash inside a PopulationSummary table so for example the hash above will look like this in PopulationSummary table:

```
    ACO, 2013, 523031
    ACO, 2012, 492349
    ACO, 2011, 432573
Org_Name, year, member_count
```

I am new to ActiveRecord methods and also to Ruby methods for working with hash,array, etc..
This is how far I got, but it looks like I have some syntax errors and also even I am not sure if the code looks good and does it even work or not. 
So if you could take a look and see what are the mistakes in the following code:

```
 POPULATION_SUMMARIES.each do |org_name, summaries|
    org_id = Organization.find_or_create_by_name(org_name).id

    summaries.each do |year, member_count|
      PopulationSummary.create (
        :organization_id => org_id,
        :year         => year,
        :member_count => member_count
      )
    end
  end
```

EDIT: With this code I am so many error, some of them for example are:

> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
>           :organization_id => org_id,
>
> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
>           :year         => year,
>
> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
>           :member_count => member_count
>                           ^

Comment: can you replace the `{` and `}` by `(` and `)`

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting. One thing I can see at a glance is that `:organization => org` should be `:organization => org_name` (unless you've defined Organization#to_s to return its name - but even then it'd be clearer to just use the org_name variable you have already).

Comment: @jvnill : replaced them...still getting so many errors. I updated my post with new code and new errors. Thanks

Comment: @micapam : Thanks, updated my code, also posted the errors...

Comment: These aren't the same thing in Ruby: `f(x, y)` and `f (x, y)`.

Comment: and mu is too short is right

Comment: oh wow, yep...that son a gun space before the open "(" fix it.  Now I don't know whose answer to mark as correct, @jvnill fixed half of it by changing "{" to "(" and mu fixed the other part . :) Thanks guys.

Comment: Ok well now syntax error are gone, let me check in pgAdmin and see if all rows are correctly even inserted or not :(